# How to remove the jQuery "html" function in a Require.JS context?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to figure out ways to force developers to use underscore templates instead of using `html(html)`  We use jQuery, Backbone, Require.js, and Underscore, and a lot of our rendering code ends up doing something like this (simplified for readability):

```
  define(['jquery','underscore','backbone'], 
      function($,_,Backbone){
        var template = _.template("<strong><%= title %></strong>");
        $('.some-div').html(template({title: model.get('name')});
      }
  );
```

About 10% of the time, I'm finding code like this in our code base, which I want to avoid. I want to force the use of templates:

```
  define(['jquery','underscore','backbone'], 
      function($,_,Backbone){
        $('.some-div').html("<strong>"+ model.get('name') +"</strong>");
      }
  );
```

I'd like to remove the jQuery `html` function in this context to force developers to use another method defined by our team ("renderTemplate") that requires that a template be used.

**How can this be done?**

Note: I know we can do this with code reviews and best practices, but I'd prefer to force devs down this path quicker, as the `html` function won't be there, and they'll ask why.

**EDIT**: I know I could remove the `html` function from the jQuery prototype, but it needs to be there for other libraries we have *outside* of the RequireJS module context. It only needs to be removed for the module context as defined above.

Comment: You wrote `$('.some-div').html(...)` in your first example. Is that a typo ?

Comment: You can be evil, and remove it from the jQuery object prototype. Or you can be even more evil, and edit the function definition in the imported `jQuery.js`...

Comment: You realize that if `html` were no longer usable, your first example wouldn't work since it also relies on `html`?

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. It can't be removed from the jQuery prototype because Backbone may need it in some cases for View stuff. So it can only be removed in this anonymous function Require.JS context. I'll clarify my question a bit more.

Comment: @DavidSulc: Good point. We'd probably rename the "html" function to something else, usable by our "renderTemplate" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Mappings Only

Here's one way to do it, using only mappings. This is adapted from the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap) about how to load jQuery with the `noConflict` call.

You you need a `jquery-private` module that performs the excision:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  $.noConflict();
  delete $.fn.html;
  return $;
});
```

And the following configuration:

```
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "./js",
    paths: {
       jquery: 'jquery-1.10.2'
    },
    map: {
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery' },
      'restricted': {'jquery': 'jquery-private'}
    }
  });
```

In the code above only the module named `restricted` would be prevented from using the `html` method. In a real project, you would probably want to use an algorithm to list all the modules that must be restricted. They would all have to use the same mapping as `restricted` above.

The basic principle is that jQuery is loaded twice. The modules like `restricted` load `jquery-private` whenever they request `jquery` and they get the modified version. Everything else gets the unaltered version.

Note that the `map` option comes with a serious [caveat](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map): it does not work with relative module names.

#### Contexts

Here's another way to do it, using contexts. And here is a configuration and main code illustrating how it works:

```
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "./js",
    paths: {
       jquery: 'jquery-1.10.2'
    }
  });

  require(["jquery"], function ($) {
     console.log($("body").html);
  });

  var rr = require.config({
    context: "restricted",
    baseUrl: "./js",
    paths: {
       jquery: 'jquery-1.10.2'
    },
    map: {
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
      'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
  });

  rr(["jquery"], function ($) {
     console.log($("body").html);
  });
```

Here too jQuery is loaded twice. It is loaded once in the default context and left intact there. This first load is also the one that sets `$` and `jQuery` in the global space. It is loaded a second time in the `restricted` context, and there the `html` method is excised. All restricted code must be loaded in the `restricted` context. Code that must have access to `html` must be loaded with the default context.

Comment: I'm pretty new to RequireJS and hoped this was possible... Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: and for anyone like myself that's new to this, if you want to switch it so the default context is the one that has jQuery restricted, just swap them as you'd think, and move the `context:restricted` line to the default `require.config` block instead.

Comment: and [here's a git repo for testing it out](https://github.com/bradparks/how-to-remove-jquery-html-function-in-require-js-context)